# citation undefined - Bibliography

Tags: biblatex

If this is my file.tex:

```
Ras is capable of binding tightly to downstream effector molecules and 
thereby propagate specific signaling pathways \cite{12581669}
```

and this my biblio.bib:

```
@article{12581669,
  author = {Herrmann, C.},
  title = {Ras-effector interactions: after one decade},
  year = 2003,
  journal = {Current opinion in structural biology},
  volume = 13,
  number = 1,
  pages = {122--9},
  pmid = 12581669,
  keywords = {}
}
```

I get:

```
citation '12581669' on page 1 undefined.
```

and the numbering is "?"**

Some idea of what should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you run `bibtex`? (And you're not actually using `\usepackage{biblatex}` as the tag suggests, are you?)

Comment: a likely duplicate: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/579)